# If questions are asking for off-site resources, shouldn't answers that provide only off-site resources be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

Using this question *[Check status of one port on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168317/check-status-of-one-port-on-remote-host)* and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35965841/3956566) as an example:

I've screenshot the answer, for future reference, in case it is deleted:

[image]

Should answers that just recommend an off-site resource with little other input be on-topic for the site?

Can this answer be flagged as NAA based on the off-site resource recommendation and little else?

Comment: Another answer on the same question that was Larsoned http://i.stack.imgur.com/gCQEj.png

Comment: Larsoned == arsoned with an L. @BhargavRao

Comment: @BhargavRao Larsoned.. \*slow clap\*

Comment: To those who don't know what is *Larsoned* http://i.stack.imgur.com/DndWh.png

Comment: Please don't dig up old stuff from the first 2 years of SO, it is a waste of your time and ours.  Life was much simpler back then, people just shared what they knew and every question got enough answers to give everybody a chance to find something useful back.  There were no stone tablets yet that dictated proper form, no need to dodge reviewers that spend 6 seconds on post, no need to survive a chat room raiding party, no demerit for posting a correct answer to a crappy question.  What happened in 2009 needs to stay in 2009.

Comment: @HansPassant in defense of the OP, the question wasn't a dig up, it attracted new poo as we like to call it. As the Q/A pair becomes active it attracts at least our attention. We rather flesh out the correct moderation action here on meta instead of in some backroom or Github. That is something you and some other MSO regulars wanted us to do, IIRC. I assume my answer is in line with what your comment suggests?

Comment: I don't really understand why a 7 year old question needs attention.  There are 12,000 new ones every day, focus your energy on the ones that actually matter and most directly affect what this site looks like.  If that needs to be enshrined in a "process" then set the simple rule that moderating old content is not productive.

Comment: I would argue that the question itself is off topic. Deal with the question instead.

Comment: @Braiam that is probably worthwhile putting into an answer.

Answer (score 11):

I've said this a thousand times:

## When you see a smelly answer, the question reeks worse

in other words: deal with the question

If you see an answer that in your view is problematic, chances are that the question itself is problematic. Deal with the question instead.

Answer (score 5):

Answers are never off-topic, questions might be and some questions become off-topic over time as [Hans Passant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318875/if-questions-asking-for-off-site-resources-shouldnt-answers-that-provide-only#comment321296_318875) already mentioned.

That brand new answer on a question from 2009 isn't qualifying for an Not An Answer (NAA) flag, because without looking at the context, it isn't of the form *`[Look here](http://awesomeproduct.example.com)`*. Instead it provides a bit more information and names the product.

Although the question might explicitly state *no libraries* there is no rule that forbids such answers. The OP shouldn't be amazed to get at least a downvote from the asker and for sure don't expect to ever become the accepted answer.

You have a few options here:

- Downvote the answer (based on your reasoning that is a valid option)
- Protect the question if it attracts new, low quality of non-sense answers
- Close vote the question if the question is off-topic by today's standards and attracts new answers from users that aren't blocked by the protection meassure

In this case I would **ONLY** downvote the new answer and leave the question alone. At the moment we need the moderation resources on fresh questions.

Comment: s/Protect/Close/